# memory swap for a 128GB of ram job on 24GB of ram machine

Tags: hard-drive, memory, swap

Doing some work using machine learning I need to train a model for my language. Since they only provide english german and spanish they advise to take the wikipedia corpus and train the model with that.

The issue is that they advise 128GB of ram. The machine I would train it on has 24GB of RAM and less than 100GB of free disk space.

Can I make a swap that fills up the whole disk? With 75% of the ram beeing on the disk the job is probably going to take 100% longer no (they already say more than a day on a good machine)?

Is it reasonable to try on a 24GB machine with mostly swap memory or should I look for an AWS VM that has the right requirements from the get go?

Comment: "100% longer" is a vast understatement. Disk swap is so slow (especially if you're on a HDD) you're probably looking at *least* 1000% longer. Even that might be off by an order of magnitude or two.

Comment: Ok, so it probably isn't a reasonable solution. Thanks I'll look for an other machine or an already  trained model.

Comment: @Bob from experience (a 3 second Matlab job wanting over 30GB memory on a system with 4GB RAM after auto-coding into C) it was a factor of roughly 700.  Of course this will vary based on what exactly is being run.  And if it takes about a day on a "good machine" you'd still be looking at two years of training with that too...  You could almost buy a decent (enough) machine for the job with the electricity costs saved.